# VS 2012 - XP Issues

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-xp

I installed VS 2012 Professional and the XP update as well. I built my project with `v110_xp` as the platform toolset on VS 2012. My project's .msi package is installing fine on Win 7 but failing on Win XP SP3. The error reported on XP SP3 is -

> "The procedure entry point FlushProcessWriteBuffers could not be
>   located in the dynamic link library Kernel32.dll".

While the same project built from VS 2005 is installing fine on XP SP3. I am not sure what is going on VS 2012. `_WIN32_WINNT` is set to `0x0501`. Can some one please guide as how to resolve the problem ?

Any help is highly appreciated,

Mahesh.

Comment: According to MSDN, that function is Vista+.

Comment: @chris I see that. But how come it was working fine when package is built on VS 2005 is what I don't understand at this point.

Comment: Because the VS2005 runtime does not attempt to link to that function. But the VS2012 runtime that you deploy does.

Comment: Thanks for this question. It helps me a lot, too. I'm just wondering why we make the same mistake :p

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the C Runtime has a dependency on FlushProcessWriteBuffers().  The updated version of msvcrt110.dll and libcmtl.lib, the ones you got along with the update, no longer directly link to the function, they use GetProcAddress() to find it and limp along if it is missng.  So you should never get this error.

So very high odds that you deployed the wrong version of msvcrt110.dll, an old one instead of the updated one.  You can find it back in c:\windows\system32, look at the properties.  Mine is version 11.00.51106.1, dated 11/5/2012.  A separate installer is available for it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

Comment: You are correct. I packaged the wrong dlls. My project is building and placed the correct dlls to package. Let you know how it goes. Hope it succeeds on XP :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: This is not going to well.  Why don't you just use the installer that I linked and get it over with?  Then take all the time you need to find out what is wrong with yours.

Comment: @Mahesh It's pretty clear that your question has been answered. I think that last comment from Hans is the advice you need.

Answer (score 3):

The VS2012 runtime that you are installing uses functions that are not present available in XP. See this MS article: [Targeting Windows XP with C++ in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/06/15/10320645.aspx) which explains more and provides some workarounds.

[Update 1](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update#story-update-1) for VS2012 resolve the problem.

> But Update 1 isn’t just about new Windows platforms. It also enables you to target Windows XP with native C++ applications in Visual Studio 2012.

If you are building with update 1 and still encountering problems then I suspect that you are installing an out of date runtime. You need to deploy the runtime delivered with update 1.

Comment: There was an update. There's now a compiler for it. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-update#story-update-1

Comment: @David You gave me a hint. What I have packaged C, C++ runtimes in my .msi aren't the latest ones supported for XP. Let me see how it goes after having the supported C,C++ runtimes. But anyhow the function is looked in Kernel32.dll and not in the C, C++ runtimes. I will give a try anyhow.

Comment: @Mahesh My final paragraph says the same as what you just said. The C runtime that you are deploying is looking for a Windows API function that doesn't exist in XP. That API function lives in kernel32, but only in Vista and up. So it's the runtime trying to load a function in kernel32 that doesn't exist on XP. The problem is in the runtime. The fact that the error message mentions kernel32 doesn't mean the problem lies in kernel32.

Comment: Did you deploy the 32 bit version instead of 64 bit version, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by including the VC11 merge modules from your development machine(program files\common files\merge modules) in your installer. It's easier than having to run the redist exe in your installer.

If you use WIX: [merge module addition](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/authoring_merge_modules.htm)

I've tested on server 03, xp64 and xp32.